# Сортировка двух файлов json на общий вывод?

Tags: python, json, for

Делаю для модуля gendiff который будет принимать двай файла gendiff filepath1.json filepath2.json. Хочу понять как оптимальнее сделать алгоритм сортировки, чем просто через for?

Вывести изменения json файлов относительно друг друга, ключи выводятся в алфавитном порядке. Отсутствие плюса или минуса говорит о том, что ключ есть в обоих файлах, и его значения совпадают. Во всех остальных ситуациях значение по ключу либо отличается, либо ключ есть только одном файле. В примере выше ключ timeout есть в обоих файлах, но имеет разные значения, proxy находится только в filepath1.json, а verbose только в filepath2.json.
Вывод

```
{
  - follow: false
    host: hexlet.io
  - proxy: 123.234.53.22
  - timeout: 50
  + timeout: 20
  + verbose: true
}


filepath1 = {
    "host": "hexlet.io",
    "timeout": 50,
    "proxy": "123.234.53.22",
    "follow": False
}

filepath2 = {
    "timeout": 20,
    "verbose": True,
    "host": "hexlet.io"
}
```

Сравниваются данные, а не строки файлов.
Две строки дифа, отвечающие за различия общего поля, должны находиться рядом. Причём вначале выводится строка, относящаяся к первому файлу, а затем строка, относящаяся ко второму файлу (см. пример с timeout).

Решение перебором

```
print('{')
for i in sorted(filepath1.items()):
    if i in filepath2.items():
        print(' ', *i)
    elif i not in filepath2.items():
        print(' -', *i)


for j in sorted(filepath2.items()):
    if j not in filepath1.items():
        print(' +', *j)
print('}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать фильтры. Итерация через них ускоряет скорость работы программы, особенно, если сравнивать скорость работы на больших массивах данных.

`new` - Множество ключей, которые отсутствуют в первом словаре, но присутствуют во втором.

`delete` - Множество ключей, которые отсутствуют во втором словаре, но присутствуют в первом.

`changed` - Множество ключей, значения которых поменялись во втором словаре.

Перейдём к коду:

```
filepath1 = {
"host": "hexlet.io",
"timeout": 50,
"proxy": "123.234.53.22",
"follow": False
}

filepath2 = {
    "timeout": 20,
    "verbose": True,
    "host": "hexlet.io"
}

f1k = filepath1.keys()
f2k = filepath2.keys()

new = set(filter(lambda x: x not in f1k, f2k))
deleted = set(filter(lambda x: x not in f2k, f1k))
changed = set(filter(lambda x: x not in new and x not in deleted and filepath2[x] != filepath1[x], f2k))

print('{')
for i in sorted(filepath1.items()):
  k, v = i
  if k in changed:
      print(' -', k, v)
      print(' +', k, filepath2[k])
  elif k in deleted:
      print(' -', k, v)
  else:
    print(' ', k, v)
for k in new:
  print(' +', k, filepath2[k])
print('}')
```